# Unable to use variable value in makefile target

Tags: makefile

My Makefile is as below:

```
install_xyz:
            cd xyz && ... make install
```

After this a directory gets created under `xyz/target/abcd`. I want to store this directory name `abcd` in a variable. All this needs to be done under the target `install_xyz`. I want to use the variable value in subsequent commands under the `install_xyz` target.

Answer (score 0):

Each line in a makefile recipe is run in its own shell. You **cannot** directly share shell variables between them.

You have a few choices.

1. Use a make variable for the name/etc. instead of a shell variable. (Only works if you can determine the name ahead of time.)
2. Use a "single line" recipe through `\` continuation of the recipe lines.
3. Store the variables to a temporary file and read it back on on each subsequent line that needs it.

Comment: Thanks Etan. If I go with 3. I have to do something like:path=$(shell cat /tmp/tmp.txt) && cp -r xyz/$path/include/* pqr/include/ . But the path value is empty. Could you please help.

Comment: No, don't use `$(shell)` in a recipe context. Just read the value using shell commands/etc. Though three is my least recommended option for the record.